# Get the number of rows created for each month over a year

Tags: mysql

I have a db table named `APPLICATION` that has the following columns

```
applicationnumber varchar,
createddate datetime, 
applicantname varchar, 
material varchar, 
location varchar
```

I am needed to write a query that would display the number of applications created for each month for the locations

Eg. The query result should be something like below

```
Location  | Jan2012 | Feb2012 | Mar2012 | Apr2012 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
London | 34322342 | 4342424 | 54353454 | 5434  
Chicago| 43242345 | 9943455 | 85748294 | 544
```

The result is the number of applications created in each month for the specific location.

Each column will execute the same query logic, with just the month changing.
I tried using the `MONTH()` function, but I need the month matrix as a column and not as a row.

Comment: What is the 34322342... numbers

Comment: You need something like pivot table http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Pivot_table

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DATE_FORMAT` function on the createddate field to only get the month and year  and then `GROUP BY` location. Something like this should do it:

```
SELECT
    `location`,
    COUNT(`applicationnumber`),
    DATE_FORMAT(`createddate`, '%M %Y') AS `date`
FROM `APPLICATION`
GROUP BY `location`;
```

Should give a result with the count of rows per month.

Comment: Really thanks for the quick response. 

The query mentioned returns me columns like Location, Count, Month  and values London, 92, January 2012 <row2> London, 67, December 2012 <row3> Chicago, 54, January 2013. What i was actually looking for is columns something like Location, Jan2012, Feb2012 with values London, 932, 432 <row2> Chicago, 432, 0